kmalloc_size_index conversion table order
Why the order of kmem_cache indexes is that?
  /*
   * Conversion table for small slabs sizes / 8 to the index in the
   * kmalloc array. This is necessary for slabs < 192 since we have non power
   * of two cache sizes there. The size of larger slabs can be determined using
   * fls.
   */
  u8 kmalloc_size_index[24] __ro_after_init = {
          3,      /* 8 */
          4,      /* 16 */
          5,      /* 24 */
          5,      /* 32 */
          6,      /* 40 */
          6,      /* 48 */
          6,      /* 56 */
          6,      /* 64 */
          1,      /* 72 */
          1,      /* 80 */
          1,      /* 88 */
          1,      /* 96 */
          7,      /* 104 */
          7,      /* 112 */
          7,      /* 120 */
          7,      /* 128 */
          2,      /* 136 */
          2,      /* 144 */
          2,      /* 152 */
          2,      /* 160 */
          2,      /* 168 */
          2,      /* 176 */
          2,      /* 184 */
          2       /* 192 */
  };

Why not to use more human expected order of the indexes? I mean why the values in the index are not sequential in [1, 7]? E.g. why the index for sizes in [8, 16) bytes is 3 and not 1?
The original commit at 9e5e8deca746 doesn't give that information.
False sharing here doesn't seem to be a thing. Beside that the original commit doesn't help in it's description why that order of elements was chosen. LKML doesn't have discussion of this too: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20070618095915.826976488@sgi.com/ .

The array-table kmalloc_size_index actually maps to kmem caches with increasing sizes.
The thing is that the mapping is indirect, via indices in kmem caches array. And the first elements in that array are not ordered by size:
const struct kmalloc_info_struct kmalloc_info[] __initconst = {
    INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(0, 0),
    INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(96, 96),
    INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(192, 192),
    INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(8, 8),
    INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(16, 16),
    INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(32, 32),
    INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(64, 64),
    INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(128, 128),
    INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(256, 256),
    ...
};

Would you arrange indexes in the kmalloc_info array with increasing sizes, you get:

0 - INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(0, 0)
3 - INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(8, 8)
4 - INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(16, 16)
5 - INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(32, 32)
6 - INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(64, 64)
1 - INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(96, 96)
7 - INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(128, 128)
2 - INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(192, 192)
8 - INIT_KMALLOC_INFO(256, 256)
...

As you could find, indices referenced in kmalloc_size_index table are in the same order, so they represent caches with increasing size.

So the true answer is in 8a965b3baa89ffedc73c0fbc750006c631012ced . This is the reason where that strange order for initialization comes from - caches with odd sizes (96,192) must be initialized first.
